# java hashmap seems to allow 2 duplicate keys

Tags: java, json, hashmap, gson

Executing the following code:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Util util = new Util();
        util.addBlock(1);
        util.addBlocks(util.getBlocks());
    }

}

public class Util {

    public static HashMap<Long, Integer> blockMap = new HashMap<>();
    private Gson gson = new Gson();

    public void addBlocks(String json){
        Map map = gson.fromJson(json, Map.class);
        blockMap.putAll(map);
        System.out.println(blockMap.keySet());
    }

    public void addBlock(int i){
        blockMap.put(0L, i);
    }

    public String getBlocks(){
        return gson.toJson(blockMap);
    }
}
```

I get the output

```
[0, 0]
```

from the print `System.out.println(blockMap.keySet());`.

So, for some reason, I have a `Map<Long, Integer>` that contains two `Long`s with value `0` as key. And a keyset `Set<Long>` with two `0`s. But map and set do not allow duplicate keys, how is this possible?

---

The code first adds a simple entry to the map:

```
blockMap.put(0L, i);
```

Then, I add another entry by converting the map to a JSON string, using GSON and then back to a map:

```
gson.toJson(blockMap);
...
Map map = gson.fromJson(json, Map.class);
blockMap.putAll(map);
```

I would expect that it overwrites the previous entry and not adds another entry with the same, duplicate, key.

Comment: Can you post a [mcve]?

Comment: I disagree. I just tried exactly the provided code and this prints out what the op said.

Comment: @Schottky OPs code is **not complete**, how could you execute it *as-it-is*? `Block` and the JSON payload are missing. Please share the full code, then others can also reproduce and investigate.

Comment: What is `Block` class?

Comment: I used Block as a simple class with two properties string and a long. getToken() simply returns the long and I can reproduce the duplicate key issue

Comment: I removed the block class completely and made things simpler, how do i post new code here

Comment: You are using `putAll` but providing a raw `Map` without generics. That is dangerous and you should be get serious warnings for that. Generics are erased at runtime. This could allow you to pollute your map with, lets say `Integer`s instead of `Long`s. So maybe one of your `0` is a `Long` while the other is `Integer`, who knows. Just guessing here. One of the reasons you should never ever use raw types.

Comment: @martse Just [edit] your question.

Comment: Zabusa i think you are right, i should not provide raw Map. Still it is interestring that this happens.

Comment: @Zabuza that is the issue. Using this implementation, one key is a String and another key is a Long

Comment: Does hashmap allow one key to be string when it is defined that key should be long?

Comment: Anyway thanks for your help guys, i will change some things.

Comment: You basically bypassed the generic-system. So with this, you can basically insert whatever you want in your map, not only `Long`. The map works the same still though, it will not allow duplicates. But by being able to insert whatever you want, you can easily insert stuff that looks similar but is actually different, like a string `"0"` vs a long `0` vs an integer `0` vs a short `0`, ... all would be considered different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Explanation

You are interpreting your results slightly wrong. You say it prints

```
[0, 0]
```

And conclude that you have two keys of type `Long` with value `0`. But that is actually wrong. One is indeed a `Long`, coming from here:

```
blockMap.put(0L, i);
```

But the other is a `String` `"0"`, which, in the print, looks the same.

---

### Raw-types

You might be confused why there is a string-key in your `HashMap<Long, Block>`. After all, it specifies the key as `Long`, not as `String`.

The issue is here:

```
Map map = gson.fromJson(json, Map.class);
blockMap.putAll(map);
```

What happens here is that you use `putAll`, but provide a `Map`. Note that it has no generics, it is a **raw-type**.

By using a raw-type, you basically sacrifice all type-safety and promise Java "Yeah, yeah, trust me, I know what I am doing.". So Java will just trust you that you actually give it a `Map<Long, Block>`, but you are actually giving it a `Map<String, String>`.

---

### Heap pollution

In Java, generics are **erased at runtime**. Meaning that, after passing compilation, Java knows nothing about generics anymore and basically allows you to mix types as you want, it is just "`Map<Object, Object>`" more or less.

So you managed to trick Javas safe generic-type-system and injected a `String` into a map that only accepts `Long`s as keys. This is called **heap pollution**. And is the major reason why you should never ever use raw-types. There is no benefit in using raw-types.

A small example of heap pollution:

```
List<Dog> dogs = new ArrayList<>(); // safe collection
dogs.add(new Dog());

// dogs.add(new Cat()); // not allowed, dogs is safe

List raw = dogs; // raw handle to safe collection
raw.add(new Cat()); // works! heap pollution

// compiles, but throws at run-time,
// since it is actually a cat, not a dog
Dog dog = dogs.get(1);
```

---

### Notes

Here is more to read about this topic:

- [Java generics type erasure: when and what happens?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339699/java-generics-type-erasure-when-and-what-happens)
- [Heap pollution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_pollution)

Comment: Why the down-vote? I would like to improve the post.

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is as @Zabuza pointed out, that you are using a raw Map without generics that are erased at runtime. Just try out this example:

```
for (Object key: Util.blockMap.keySet()) {
    System.out.println("key: " + key + " type: " + key.getClass());
}
```

and you will see that your first key is of type `Long` while the second key is of type `String`

Since the equals-method is defined inside `String` as:

```
if (anObject instanceof String) {
    // ...
}
return false;
```

equals will always return false

Answer (score 1):

I hope the following code will clear your doubt:

```
public void addBlocks(String json) {
    Map map = gson.fromJson(json, Map.class);
    blockMap.putAll(map);
    System.out.println(blockMap.keySet());
    Iterator itr=blockMap.keySet().iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(itr.next().getClass());
    }
}
```

**Output with this code:**

```
[0, 0]
class java.lang.Long
class java.lang.String
```